# Troubleshooting NFS authentication problems

Tags: logging, nfs, kerberos

I am trying to mount a krb5p NFS export. For this I have followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto).

Line in `/etc/exports`:

```
/home/users     192.168.1.0/24(rw,sec=krb5p,no_subtree_check,nohide,async,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
```

When attempting the mount on the client I get:

```
root@client:/home# mount -t nfs4 -o sec=krb5p server:/home/users /home/users/ -vvv
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: spec:  "server:/home/users"

mount: node:  "/home/users/"
mount: types: "nfs4"
mount: opts:  "sec=krb5p"
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.nfs4"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "server:/home/users"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/home/users/"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw,sec=krb5p"
mount.nfs4: timeout set for Sun May 12 14:46:22 2013
mount.nfs4: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5p,addr=192.168.1.2,clientaddr=192.168.1.82'
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting server:/home/users
```

On the server however I could find no relevant log entry or any information at all that scribes the reason on why the access was denied.

When changing the security from `krb5p` to `sys` the mount works fine.

`kinit` etc for kerberos works fine though.

How can I find out the reason why the access is being rejected? Or do you perhaps know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: try to run rpc.nfsd from command line with -d option

Comment: @tigran after struggling with this all day I have finally found it just now. `-s` on `rpc.nfsd` did the trick. I've got some seemingly more meaningful messages now, although I still don't understand them.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get some more meaningful messages on the server, by editing `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server` and adding the `-s` option `rpc.nfsd` like this:

```
# Options for rpc.nfsd.
RPCNFSDOPTS="-s"
```

When trying to do the mount, that gave me the output:

```
May 12 19:59:48 server krb5kdc[2704]: AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.1.62: NEEDED_PREAUTH: nfs/client.localdomain@REALM for krbtgt/REALM@REALM, Additional pre-authentication required
May 12 19:59:48 server krb5kdc[2704]: preauth (encrypted_timestamp) verify failure: Decrypt integrity check failed
May 12 19:59:48 server krb5kdc[2704]: AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.1.62: PREAUTH_FAILED: nfs/client.localdomain@REALM for krbtgt/REALM@REALM, Decrypt integrity check failed
```

No sure if that really helps me, but its one step ahead.

Comment: Made a new thread to look into that preauthentication problem in detail: http://serverfault.com/questions/507122/kerberos-pre-authentication-failed-on-nfs-mount